# Custom code management with the Composer auto loader?

Tags: php, composer-php

I've started a new project, where I use [Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) to handle some dependencies, as well as their auto-loading.

I only keep the composer.json file in the VCS, instead of the entire vendor directory, so I don't want to start adding my code in there.

How should I handle my own project specific code, so that it auto loads as well?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

This is actually very simple. Excluding vendors directory from your repository is the right approach. Your code should be stored in a separate place (like src).

Use the [autoload](http://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) property to make that composer recognizes your namespace(s):

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Acme\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming you have class names following the psr-4 standard, it should work. Below some example of class names and their locations on the file system:

- Acme\Command\HelloCommand -> src/Command/HelloCommand.php
- Acme\Form\Type\EmployeeType -> src/Form/Type/EmployeeType.php

Remember to define a namespace for each class. Here's an example of Acme\Command\HelloCommand:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Command;

class HelloCommand
{
}
```

Don't forget to include the autoloader in your PHP controllers:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

Read more on [PSR-4 standard on PHP Framework Interoperability Group](https://github.com/php-fig/fig-standards/blob/master/accepted/PSR-4-autoloader.md).

Note that if you edit `composer.json`, you need to either run install, update or [dump-autoload](http://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload) to refresh the autoloader class paths.

Comment: Any chance you could post update the answer with simple code examples with a dummy class or two? Despite reading the documentation you linked to, and comparing my directory/namespacing with those used in vendor/, I can't get my classes to load.