# Composer psr-0 autoloading of custom namespaces does not work

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, autoloader, psr-0

I have trouble adding my own namespaces to composer with PSR-0. I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12247431/custom-code-management-with-the-composer-auto-loader/12248348#12248348%20) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18146057/composer-autoloader-psr-0-namespaces) but I still can't make it work

composer.json

```
{
"require": {
    "klein/klein": "2.0.x",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.4"

},
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "mynamespace":        "src/"
        }
}
}
```

The `src` folder is placed inside the same directory as `composer.json`

The `src` directory has the following structure

```
src
└── mynamespace
    ├── Keys.php
```

Keys.php

```
<?php
namespace mynamespace\Keys;

define ("API_KEY", "XXXXXXXXXXXX");
?>
```

index.php

```
use Klein\Klein;
use mynamespace\Keys;
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$klein = new Klein(); // works
echo API_KEY;  // Undefined constant
```

Comment: PSR-x autoloaders only "understand" single-namespace single-class include scripts. Even if they did provide full language support, PHPs current spl_autoload() does not recognize constant or plain function lookups. The `echo API_KEY` does not trigger anything, neither does the `use ..\Keys` declaration.

Comment: @mario so I have to use require to load my own namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only load classes, interfaces and traits with autoloading.

Because all you do is add a `use` clause which does not do anything by itself with autoloading (i.e. it does not load something), and you do not use a class, nothing happens.

I recommend using class constants. They may be put into classes or interfaces:

```
namespace mynamespace;

interface Keys {
    const API_KEY = 'XXXXXXXX';
}

use mynamespace/Keys;
echo Keys::API_KEY;
```