# Can't create 'new Class' even after including it

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm using the googleAds API, but when I include a class that I need in my function
it still shows me an error :

> Error: Class 'TargetingIdeaSelector' not found
>   File: C:\wamp64\www\projet\app\Model\Keyword.php
>   Line: 26

I'm including it like this :

```
include 'C:\wamp64\www\projet\vendors\googleads\googleads_php_lib\src\Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\TargetingIdeaSelector.php';
```

And further in my function, I'm using this :

```
// Create selector.
$selector = new TargetingIdeaSelector();
```

Bringing me the error above.
Is there something else to do to use a class previously included ?

Comment: Replaced all '\' with '\\' still throwing the same error, it's still able to locate the folder to include but can't instantiate a class

Comment: You've been told in a previous question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50605057/how-to-include-adwords-in-a-cakephp-model-to-be-able-to-use-its-classes) to use composer https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib this lib features composer. You still have not learned how to use composer or how to implement your own auto-loader. https://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/

Comment: I tried to use the autoloader, but like I answered, I just can't understand how I need to adapt it to works in my case.
I added "require": { "googleads/googleads-php-lib" : "*" } in my composer.json file. But I don't know how to link everything together.
That's why I tried with include and because it found the folder, I thought it could work that way.

Comment: What is the class name defined in the TargetingIdeaSelector.php file? Is it "TargetingIdeaSelector"? Remember that capitalization matters.

Comment: It is : <?php 

namespace Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o;


/** 
 * This file was generated from WSDL. DO NOT EDIT. 
 */ 
class TargetingIdeaSelector 
{ ... }

Comment: The class is in a namespace. Have you `use`d the namespace so that PHP knows where to find it? This is in *addition to* including the file with the implementation (whether that happens manually or through the autoloader).

Comment: I included the php file "TargetingIdeaSelector.php", used the namespace  Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o and required the autoload.php, did I mixed actions ?

Answer (score 1):

Got a fix from someone better than me :

```
 require_once __DIR__ . '../../Vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\TargetingIdeaSelector;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\LanguageSearchParameter;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\o\RelatedToQuerySearchParameter;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\Language;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201710\cm\Paging;
```

It was all about using the good namespaces, I just was overloaded by the quantity of files in my project and couldn't figure out the solution out of my mess.
My bad :)

Comment: version changed so I had to updated to `v201809` but this is the correct answer.